# Django mezzanine - set url for a "blog page" as homepage ? How?

Tags: python, django

Django Mezzanine :

I have some pages and posts in my mezzanine blog. I created a page named "test" , and its url is localhost:8000/test  . Can I make that "blogpage" 'test' as homepage . I mean, at localhost:8000, it should show the content of localhost:8000/test without doing redircection from home to /test. In the admin, I am unable to keep the url for that page as homepage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making the homepage an editable page object is covered in the FAQs in the documentation:

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/frequently-asked-questions.html#why-isn-t-the-homepage-a-page-object-i-can-edit-via-the-admin